# How can I execute pip install -r requirements.txt inside Google Cloud Platform, App Engine (without using Gitlab CI)?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pip, gitlab-ci

I used to do this using Gitlab CI but I ran out of minutes. I tried deploying local virtual environment but it does not work

Comment: Hi! Did you think about Google Cloud Build?

Comment: Hi! I have just read about it. I do not think that will help me in this case

Comment: I have an app on which I execute tests before deployments. So I created a container from my source code, container in which I execute `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt`.
What exactly do you wanna do ? If you're trying to mix gitlab CI with Google I'm not sure it will be easy.

Comment: I am trying to execute something like this inside Google Cloud Platform: `pip install -e git+https://gitlab+deploy-token:commitnumber@gitlab.com/group/repository.git@1231231#egg=repositoryname`

Comment: And where? Which service? GAE, GCE, GKE, ... Be a lot more explicit please.

Comment: App Engine, inside a service

Comment: On a side note, you can increase GitLab CI job timeout by setting `timeout: 2h` (or any other timeout).

Comment: The problem is that I run out of Gitlab CI minutes. That's why I think increasing timeout does not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the GAE [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#dependencies):

> During deployment, App Engine uses the Python package manager pip to install dependencies defined in the `requirements.txt` metadata file located in your project's root directory.

You don't need to perform the `pip install` command yourself as it's done automatically. If you need to install a dependency from a VCS can do so specifying it in the `requirements.txt` file as explained in this [article](https://www.simonmweber.com/2014/11/23/git-pip-requirements.html)

Comment: It worked first me doing `pip install` locally and then deploying to GCP